# Bootstrap Grid-system is not working with image and table as column

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a specific problem with the Bootstrap Grid-system and I hope you can help me out.
I'm currently working on a aspx-file where I want to have a image on the left side and a table on the right side.

[image: this is the wanted behavior]

My problem right now is, that it doesn't appear from left to right but from up to bottom.

[image: this is the unwanted behavior]

here is my code from the aspx-file:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Import -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="formFormular1" runat="server">          
        <div>
            <uc1:SearchExtension ID="SearchExtension" runat="server"/>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <!-- Belegformular -->
                <div id="belegFormular" runat="server" class="col-lg-10">
                    <img src="about:blank" id="belegImage" alt="" runat="server" tabindex="-1" style="width: 500px;height:600px;"/>
                </div>         
            
                 <!-- Table -->
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                 <!-- the Table is called by DBDataPlaceHolder from the CodeBehind-file -->
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="DBDataPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>              
    </form>
</body>
```

I hope that somebody can help me out with that issue. Have a good day!

if it's a necessary info: I'm using IE as a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This layout may help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
</div>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col 6">
        <button style="width:100px">a</button> 
        <button style="width:100px">b</button> 
    </div>
    <div class="col 6">
        <h3>Fancy Application</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col 6" style="background-color:blue;height:100px;width:100px">
         <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-8T5K3BCEE0k/XLQsGob2TUI/AAAAAAAAFv0/-OiwdGTwoOQLlQN__xp5rHj3BQb767SHQCLcBGAs/h110/Logo%2BAgung%2BPanduan.png" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="100">
      </div>
      <div class="col 6" style="background-color:red;height:100px;width:100px">
         <table></table>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This layout may help you. If you are on a large monitor change `col-md-6` to  `col-6` or `col-lg-6`.

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class = "row col-12">
            <div class= col-md-6>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <button></button> 
                    <button></button> 
                </div>
                <img>
            </div>
            <div class= col-md-6>
                <p>Fancy Applicatiopn</p>
                <table></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this layout may help you.if you are in large monitor   change "col-md-6" to " col-6" or "col-lg-6"

Answer (score 0):

The maximum column in a bootstrap row is 12, from your code, you're using "col-lg-10" and another "col-lg-10", the browser will automatically move the second column to a different row because "10 + 10" = 20. so reduce your "col-lg-10" to col-lg-6 for both image column and table column to make up the 12 columns in a row. you can add "col-6" as well so that both remains on the same row even on smaller screens, might look weird and a little clumsy fitting all on one row on a small screen though.

Comment: unfortunately this didnt helped me at all. I still have the same issue even with changing my columns to "col-6"